# iText - how to add barcode to a Document (com.itextpdf.text.Document)?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I need to add a Barcode (or its derived image) to another Image which I've just added to a paragraph.

Also, I need to add just the Barcode part and not the text associated with it, i.e. only the vertical bars on an existing pdf. I've already openend the pdf and have a Document object.

Comment: Why wouldn't just add the image representing the barcode instead of the image you are adding to the paragraph? You can use `p.add(new Chunk(codeEAN.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null), 0, 0));` to add the barcode to the paragraph directly.

Comment: I'm explaining it in another question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42889091/1439122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setFont(null)` to avoid displaying of text associated with the barcode.

Example:

```
BarcodeEAN codeEAN = new BarcodeEAN();
codeEAN.setCode("4512345678906");
codeEAN.setFont(null);
document.add(codeEAN.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null));
```

Comment: Using Paragraph, I've already added few Image. I want to position a Barcode (or its derived Image) on top of one of the added Image to the Paragraph. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Of course I know how to do that. But that wasn't mentioned in the question *at all*, and I answered the question you asked. Feel free to post another question related to adding an image *on top of the other, already existing one*, and don't forget to include the code you have so far.

Comment: I'm explaining it in another question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42889091/1439122